# docker-compose.yml unable to start ruby app with custom configuration

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose

I have a small rack application that im configuring a development environment for, using `docker-compose.yml`

The application will be mounted to an image, without docker it runs just fine using `bundle exec rackup -p 3030`

the idea for this configuration comes from [this article](https://hackernoon.com/a-better-way-to-develop-node-js-with-docker-cd29d3a0093) for a node app, but im running into some snags when porting it over to ruby

### Makefile

```
install:
  docker-compose -f docker-compose.builder.yml run --rm install
run:
  docker-compose up
```

### docker-compose.builder.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  base:
    image: ruby:3.0.3
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/service/
    working_dir: /usr/src/service/
  install:
    extends:
      service: base
    command: bash -c "bundle config set --local path './.vendor' && bundle install"
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  dev:
    image: ruby:3.0.3
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/service
    working_dir: /usr/src/service
    command: /usr/local/bin/bundle exec ./.vendor/ruby/3.0.0/bin/rackup -p 3030
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
```

my install script seems to work just fine

```sh
$ make install
docker-compose -f docker-compose.builder.yml run --rm install
WARNING: Found orphan containers (backbone_dev_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating backbone_install_run ... done
...
Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 64 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./.vendor`
```

my issue seems to be with my script to run my app

```sh
$ make run
docker-compose up
Starting backbone_dev_1 ... done
Attaching to backbone_dev_1
dev_1  | /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: No such file or directory
backbone_dev_1 exited with code 127
```

Comment: I'd normally expect this installation work to happen in a Dockerfile, building a custom image, probably without `volumes:` involved at all.  What constraints led to this setup with multiple `docker-compose.yml` files?

Comment: I have a deployment pipeline already configured using AWS pipeline, so I dont need docker for prod deployment at this time, but for new hire onboarding im reducing the install steps to get our dev environment running on new machines. Rather than going through a long list of installs for development id like to rely on docker images.

Comment: If you can use an unmodified `ruby` image like this, then are you gaining anything over endorsing a version manager like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and checking `.ruby-version`, `Gemfile`, and `Gemfile.lock` files into source control?  If Docker is a hard requirement, can you use a Dockerfile rather than the first Compose file, to build a reusable image with fixed content?